# R ncdf4 packages install failed

Tags: package, ncdf4

I need install ncdf4 package on R 3.4.0, but it failed and told me the error "cannot find -lnetcdf". How can I install ncdf4 successfully.

```
/root/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdf
make: *** [ncdf4.so] 错误 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ncdf4’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ncdf4’

下载的程序包在
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpo9mtLQ/downloaded_packages’里
Warning message:
In install.packages("ncdf4") : 安装程序包‘ncdf4’时退出狀態的值不是0
```